# Running Perl within another Perl

Tags: perl

I have an existing perl script which I run like this in UNIX.

```
echo $query | runQuery.pl -a -f,
```

It runs a query and returns rows with -f delimiter which in above case would be ",".

I want to run the same command in another perl script where I have already defined $query and store the results in an array (@results).

I was not able to get system() work properly. Please assist.

Thanks and Regards,
-Tushar

Comment: Well, using `system()` should definitely work, so you need to provide more details on what went wrong.  An alternative is to set `@ARGV` to `('-a','-f,')` and then `require runQuery.pl` in your script.
It's a hack but it will be more efficient.

Comment: @reinierpost I am using something like this.
`my $results = system ("echo '$sql2'| runQuery.pl",@arg);`
<br>
I get error no such file or directory.

Comment: You are mixing up two ways of using `system`. Either put everything in a single argument, or split out the command and each arguments into different arguments.  Read [the documentation](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/system.html).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this ought to work for you:

```
my $arguments = '-a -f,';
my @results = `echo $query | runQuery.pl $arguments`;
```